# Stop vim from dynamically updating folds

Tags: vim

Is there any way to stop vim from automatically updating folds on the fly? I really love vim's folding, and I prefer having it in syntax mode so that folds are created as I type. But for instance when I code C++ and I write a bracket { it automatically closes all subsequent folds, and when I then close the bracket again with a }, vim automatically expands all subsequent folds, meaning that I have to refold everything.

Another related problem, if I have the same document open in a different buffer, say I have run ":split", then writing an open bracket { will nest all folds in the buffer under the fold in which I opened the bracket, and closing it will un-nest the folds but also close all of them. If I use either "." or "->" to access a member function/variable, it resets all folds in the buffer to be whatever the current foldlevel is, regardless of which folds I have opened/closed myself.

This is somewhat frustrating when I have the same document open in two buffers so I can read the contents of one function when writing another, as I constantly have to switch buffers and reopen my folds.

In my .vimrc I have

```
set foldmethod=syntax
```

and that is about it. For autocompletion I use clang-complete and supertab with:

```
let g:SuperTabDefaultCompletionType = "<c-x><c-u><c-p>"
```

I think that is everything which migh affect this.

Edit:

[Added some pictures to help illustrate the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1KECC.jpg)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Both problems can be solved with the following two `autocmd`s:

```
autocmd InsertLeave,WinEnter * setlocal foldmethod=syntax
autocmd InsertEnter,WinLeave * setlocal foldmethod=manual
```

This sets the buffer local `'foldmethod'` to `manual` when insert mode is entered or its window (a buffer display) is left, and sets it to `syntax` when insert mode is left or its window is entered.

This works because setting `'foldmethod'` to `manual` will keep the folds automatically created by `syntax` as if you set them yourself (manually), and manual folds are not updated based on the syntax of the file.

I've found two bugs with this solution:

1. When switching windows while in insert mode, the `autocmd` will set the `'foldmethod'` to `syntax` for the new window, even though it's in insert mode and should be set to `manual`.

   This isn't really a problem for me because I use Vim like a civilized person and operate in normal mode by default.
2. When

   - a new buffer is created (e.g. by reading a file)
   - and `'foldlevel'` is `0`
   - and a particular syntax is used (I'm able to duplicate the issue with a C file)
   - and the `o` or `O` command is used to enter insert mode **for the first time in that buffer** (doing `i<esc>o` does not duplicate the bug),

   then all folds below the cursor will be opened.

   I accidentally discovered this when testing the above solution, and now looking back I'm surprised I found it; it's almost not even worth mentioning. I don't intend on trying to write a test file that has the exact syntax necessary to duplicate the bug, so this may go unnoticed for another eon.

---

I actually discovered this question several months ago and used the solution Ben [linked to](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text) for a while, before eventually being annoyed enough with the multiple window for one buffer issue (your second problem) to fix it.

So thanks to Ben for his solution, and you for asking this question!

Comment: At a first glance with a bit of testing this does indeed seem to fix my issue. Of course modulo vim being a bit wierd when working with splits and multiple buffers, but that is something I have learned to live with.

Comment: "When switching windows while in insert mode"... Is this even possible?!?! Oh my... Why would someone do something like this? O.o

Answer (score 3):

I made a bit of a modification to user4830797's answer which helps deal with situations where the file you're editing doesn't use `foldmethod=syntax` (for example, a .vimrc file which might use `foldmethod=marker`):

```
autocmd InsertLeave,WinEnter * let &l:foldmethod=g:oldfoldmethod
autocmd InsertEnter,WinLeave * let g:oldfoldmethod=&l:foldmethod | setlocal foldmethod=manual
```

Comment: Error detected while processing WinEnter Autocommands for "*":
E121: Undefined variable: g:oldfoldmethod

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check `:h 'foldlevel`. You should also perhaps use `:mkview`, probably in `autocmd` which restores manually open and closed folds.

Other then that you should perhaps set folding method differently on different file types (for instance on C you could set it to manual or marker)

Comment: I would prefer to continue using syntax folding, as it generally works quite well, and I do not think foldlevel has anything to do with this.  The problem is that whenever I write something which will create a fold, all subsequent folds are opened regardless of the foldlevel

Comment: Can you try to mkview on startinsert and restore view on end insert ?

Comment: Other than the fact that it seems a bit cheaty, it had a slightly different effect. First of all it seems to fold everything following the bracket once (but not all the way), which is an improvement, I guess, but still not working. Also, if I write a bracket, write something inside it, and stop editing inside my new bracket, that will be folded when I exit insertion mode, which is less than ideal.

Comment: The later part is easily solvable by adding `zv` after restore view upon exit (open enough folds to see cursor). Seems cheaty ? :) It either works or not.

Comment: Well, I guess. It's just that closing all following folds at the automatic creation of a new fold (if that is what is happening) isn't exactly expected behaviour, and one therefore would have thought there to be a general fix, or at least an explanation. The original issue still stands though, as the only difference is that it only folds everything once, but that will still force me to re-open folds.

Comment: Have you tried setting different foldmethod on enter/exit insert ?

Comment: Yes, that seemed to do the trick for the first question =). Any idea how one might avoid the problem with the buffers (specially a split)? A simple "bufdo" did not work.

Comment: Lets reiterate old idea again - mkview on enter with bufdo restore view on exit ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. Now have Enter: `bufdo! set foldmethod=manual` then `bufdo! mkview` and when I leave I have: `bufdo! silent loadview` and then `bufdo! set foldmethod=syntax`. Also tried mixing them up, which didn't do anything. Also, aren't the views for the different buffers saved in the same file? If so that would defeat the purpose of having different views in different buffers.

Comment: Ah, u are right. Have you tried to use some plugin instead of splitting, such as NarrowRegion. Also, you don't need to use split, but you can create function that will clone current buffer to entirely different one with its own settings.

Answer (score 0):

If you temporarily set the foldmethod to manual, then Vim will keep all the folds currently defined by syntax, and keep them in the exact open/closed state you have them in now. This can be done automatically with an InsertEnter autocmd and restored on InsertLeave to protect your fold states in a single window. Unfortunately I have not yet spent time trying to get it working in split windows, but using window-local variables it is easy enough to even account for the user switching windows or something without leaving insert mode. See http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Keep_folds_closed_while_inserting_text for details and discussion.

Comment: Thanks, changing foldmethod on entering and exiting fixed the first problem, but I would very much like to fix the second one as well as splitting your window to read multiple parts of a file at once is very handy.